# How do I serially send commands (telnet) to device directly hooked up to a network?

Tags: telnet

I have a [device](http://www.gammavacuum.com/index.php/product?id=65) that typically is set up to be communicated with via telnet with a serial device server and the port it is hooked up to.

However now it is connected to a different switch, directly connecting it to the network. Is there a way to serially communicate with the device using just the IP?

Comment: Without information on the device, it is impossible to post an answer. But here's some information you can try. Some device allows telnet while others only allow ssh. Some device maps the physical ports to ip ports while others require a serial session to originate from the device itself.

Comment: This is a device that I have previously used telnet to connect to by telnetting to the serial device server at the port I connected it to. The thing I don't understand is whether a serial connection of this type can be started without using the server. But if I'm understanding you correctly, the answer to that is dependent on the device itself? Assuming it can, is there a common methodology for doing so?

Comment: Your initial question seems to imply that you have a new terminal server and wanted to access the end device. But your followup question seems to imply that the end device is no longer connected to the terminal server but it's now connected to the network.

Comment: Short answer to your question is, different devices has different network accessibility features. Windows use Remote Desktop, Linux use ssh and Mac use screen sharing. Cisco devices allow only ssh connection. So again, it boils down to the type of device.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but it is the second scenario you described. The device is no longer connected to the serial server and is instead just hooked up to a regular switch on the same network, making it directly connected to the network.

Comment: You can either ask the vendor of the device what connection is allowed on their product, or use a scanner to find an open port, figure out what protocol it talks and finally find an appropriate client tool to connect to it.

Comment: So trying to make sense of this, you are saying that the ability of a device to be serially communicated with directly is a device specific feature. However if you connect them to a serial server switch all devices can now be serially communicated with by telnetting to the server and port?

Comment: Or make it easy on the community and on you, post the device type.

Comment: Serial communication doesn't have the intricacies and layers of networking. Networking on the other hand have plenty.

Comment: I didn't initially realize it was device specific. [Here](http://www.gammavacuum.com/index.php/product?id=65) is a link to it and [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s350/sh/f31d61ca-b3a0-4a71-9d5d-ad769ff5713b/f39d065a4f8c026608c6a290c99e8c51) is a link to the manual.

Comment: The manual doesn't have any information on the ethernet connection. Either it's using http and you can use a browser to connect to it, or it's proprietary that requires an app to connect to it. Try with your browser first. Or it may even be serial over IP. Try telnetting to the ip next.

Comment: I initially tried telnetting to the IP and it does seem to set up some kind of communication but it doesn't recognize any of the commands listed in the manual. I figured maybe there was something else I needed to use.

Comment: We're you getting meaningful text or error message? Or is the output gibberish? Did you specify a specific port when you telnet to it or did you use the default port 23?